# Cambiar el color del loading de SweetAlert2

Tags: css, angular, sweetalert2

Buen día, necesito cambiar el color del loading del SweetAlert en Angular por cuestiones de diseño. 
Este es mi código del SweetAlert

```
Swal.fire({
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  icon:'info',
  title: 'Prueba del loading'
});
Swal.showLoading();
```

Usando la herramienta Inspeccionar del navegador, he visto que tiene estas clases `class="swal2-confirm swal2-styled"`. y estos estilos:

```
element.style {
    display: inline-block;
    border-left-color: rgb(48, 133, 214);
    border-right-color: rgb(48, 133, 214);
}
```

Las he implementado en los estilos generales `styles.css` de esta manera:

```
.swal2-confirm .swal2-styled {
        border-left-color: #5D5D5D !important;
        border-right-color: #5D5D5D !important;
    }
```

sin conseguir lo que necesito. No se si lo estoy haciendo mal o ¿me falta algo?

Comment: Tienes una propiedad que es `customClass` le puedes pasar tus clases https://sweetalert2.github.io/#configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer no me había percatado de un tonto detalle, y es que tenía las clases invertidas, vaya error garrafal de mi parte.

Volviendo a revisar los estilos en el navegador me percaté de ese detalle. Este es el código que se muestra en la consola del navegador:

```
.swal2-styled.swal2-confirm {
    border: 0;
    border-radius: .25em;
    background: initial;
    background-color: #3085d6;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.0625em;
}
```

Corrigiendo el error, así quedó mi código:

```
.swal2-styled.swal2-confirm  {
    border-left-color: #5D5D5D !important;
    border-right-color: #5D5D5D !important;
}
```

De esta manera logré cambiar el color del loading.